# How do I create a cube made out of smaller cubes (voxels)?

Tags: graphics, 3d, voxel, direct3d11

I am a graphics newbie so I am asking for opinions/suggestions.

I want to create (and render) a big cube that is made out of smaller cubes (voxels). The trick is that I want to be able to remove voxels at will.

One way is to use instanced rendering. In Direct3D, I could use two buffers:
The first buffer would contain the data for a single instance of a cube (e.g. vertex positions, texture coordinates, normals, etc).
The second buffer would contain the position for every voxel in a second buffer.

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility. Depending on the number of voxels, it might be better to extract the visible surface first.

Comment: another possibility is to use 3D texture to store your  voxel data... see [How to best write a voxel engine in C with performance in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to render voxels with their various pros and cons. From the question it sounds like you are going for something like a Minecraft scenario.

A fairly simple to implement method with reasonable performance is simply to break the world up into "chunks" of some fixed size. Each of these chunks has an associated vertex buffer and when a block is removed or changed in some way the vertex buffer for that chunk is updated. When rendering a draw call is issued for each chunk.

Selecting the right dimensions for a chunk is very important for performance. If your chunks are too big then rebuilding the vertex buffer when a block changes will be costly. If the chunks are too small then the total number of chunks will be large an introduce driver overhead when rendering them all.

To improve performance further burying algorithms can be applied to avoid adding hidden triangles to the vertex buffers.

There is much, much more you can do to improve performance and push the limits of how may voxels you can render but this is a good place to start.

Comment: Hi Khan. No, I am not going for something like a Minecraft scenario. Quite the opposite, I am just trying to render a big cube as a collection of smaller cubes.

Answer (score 0):

First I am assuming that your big cubes are dynamic : they can move / rotate and also their voxels can be made hidden / visible dynamically. If everything is static there are better ways to do it than this answer.

Instancing as you describe it is a good solution in terms of performance as there will be only one draw call to render all the voxels (compared to rendering each voxel one by one)

Now to be able to hide any voxel here is a trick you can use: in your instancing data buffer you can **add a scale value** along with the position, then simply **set the scale to zero when you want to hide the voxel**.